# Return result from async function in node js

Tags: node.js, parsing, asynchronous, async-await, async.js

Im using this lab in node js https://github.com/pste/youtube.get-video-info

The task is to write result from async fuction to global array

```
var yt = require('youtube.get-video-info');

var outQueue = []; // global array

function getQueue(idName){

 yt.retrieve(idName, function(err, res) { // async function

    if (err) throw err;

    var result = ybVideoName(res);

    outQueue.push(result);
                                
 }); 
}


function ybVideoName(res){ // function to get youtube name from json

  var body = res.watch_next_response;

  let params = JSON.parse(body);   

  let jsonBody = params.contents.twoColumnWatchNextResults.results.results.contents;

  let jsonBodyget = jsonBody[0];

  let itog = jsonBodyget.videoPrimaryInfoRenderer.title.runs[0].text;

  itog = itog.replace(/[+]/g, ' ');

  return itog;

}
```

Im tried to use promise and async functions but filed.

Function ybVideoName its a method to get name of youtube video.

Maybe some libs can help me?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a little time to rework the youtube.get-video-info into a more modern approach using axios.js as the library for making the request to Youtube. My fork is here: https://github.com/andrunix/youtube.get-video-info. You need to install axios as a dependency. And you can remove 'request' as a dependency since it is deprecated.

This allowed me to convert the code to use async/await. You will still have to wrap your code in an async function but. Here's how I did it.

```
// https://github.com/andrunix/youtube.get-video-info

const yt = require('./youtube.get-video-info.js');
const outQueue = [];

async function getQueue(idName){
    let result = await yt.retrieve(idName);
    outQueue.push(ybVideoName(result));
}

function ybVideoName(res){ // function to get youtube name from json
    const body = res.watch_next_response;
    let params = JSON.parse(body);
    let jsonBody = params.contents.twoColumnWatchNextResults.results.results.contents;
    let jsonBodyget = jsonBody[0];
    let itog = jsonBodyget.videoPrimaryInfoRenderer.title.runs[0].text;
    return itog.replace(/[+]/g, ' ');
}

(async () => {
    await getQueue('ml-v1bgMJDQ');
    console.log(outQueue);
})();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, it work

But this result prevents me from accessing the global variable in other functions.

The point is that a large queue comes from the client, each element needs to be processed and put into the output queue

How can you make it possible to access the global array later without using the getQueue () function?

Comment: thanks man, i try to use this code. Some later take this answer to right